# Python: Plot Different Figure Background Color For Each Row of Subplots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, figure

I have a figure of 9 sibplots (3 rows x 3 columns). I would like to plot the background color of the figure (not the subplots!) in a different color for each row. This is what I have so far:

```
# Imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Plot the Figure

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=(9, 9))

for r in np.arange(3):
    for c in np.arange(3):
        axes[r, c].plot(np.arange(10), np.random.randint(10, size=10))
        if r == 0:
            axes[r, c].patch.set_facecolor('azure')
        if r == 1:
            axes[r, c].patch.set_facecolor('hotpink')
        if r == 2:
            axes[r, c].patch.set_facecolor('lightyellow')
plt.show()
```

This figure is wrong in the sense that it colors the background inside each subplot. But what I want is to color the figure background (outside the subplots) differently for each row. How can I do this?

Comment: The figure has only one single background. So if you need different colors you need to create several rectangles and place them in the figure.

Comment: I see. Thank you! Do you know how I can add three such rectangles in the figure behind the subplots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=(9, 9))

for r in np.arange(3):
    for c in np.arange(3):
        axes[r, c].plot(np.arange(10), np.random.randint(10, size=10))

colors = ['azure','hotpink','lightyellow']
for ax,color in zip(axes[:,0],colors):
    bbox = ax.get_position()
    rect = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((0,bbox.y0),1,bbox.height, color=color, zorder=-1)
    fig.add_artist(rect)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Code for matplotlib.__version__<3.0**

The following code works in older version of matplotlib where `Figure.add_artist()` does not exist. However, I found that adding the rectangle to one of the axes causes problem for that axes background patch, so I had to hide all the backgrounds for a consistent look.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3)

for r in np.arange(3):
    for c in np.arange(3):
        axes[r, c].plot(np.arange(10), np.random.randint(10, size=10))

fig.tight_layout()

colors = ['azure','hotpink','lightyellow']
for ax,color in zip(axes[:,0],colors):
    bbox = ax.get_position()
    rect = Rectangle((0,bbox.y0),1,bbox.height, color=color, zorder=-1, transform=fig.transFigure, clip_on=False)
    ax.add_artist(rect)
for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This may work, but I get an error saying:   AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'add_artist'.    Do you know how I can get around that error?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @JohanC but I don't think that works, because then we do not plot any colored backgrounds/rectangles.

Comment: @kirerik The above code works correctly for me using `fig.add_artist`. Maybe you're running an old version of matplotlib, or maybe your code somewhere overwrote the `fig` from `plt.subplots`

Comment: I am using python 3.4 and I have tried to copy the code suggested by Diziet Asahi line-by-line.

Comment: What version of matplotlib? Figure.add_artist() was added in matplotlib 3.0 apparently

Comment: @kirerik I've added a solution that works without Figure.add_artist()

Comment: That's perfect! That was precisely the outcome I wanted. Thank you very much!